# Break AG Cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a 2 node cluster setup and we use AlwaysOn HA with it.  Currently we have two AG's and each one has three separate databases in each AG.  We want to break the cluster and have three databases stay online and active on node A and the other three databases stay active on node B.

Our plan is to:

1. Failover second set of three databases to the node B
2. Remove the three databases from the AG database list
3. Create DNS alias for the two listeners and point one to node A and
   the other to node B

Does this sound like it is feasible or are we way off base?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you are wanting to break the cluster and always on and have 3 db's on each server?   If so you plan sounds good but after you move the 3 db's to node B  I would create DNS names that point to both node A/B as necessary before removing them from the AG and deleting off node A.  That way anything using the DNS as a connection will work once the cluster is broken.   I believe the listeners will be deleted as well if you break the cluster.  Hope I understood correctly.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing.  Thanks for the response.